# NSJSONSerialization cannot load large json data from URL

Tags: ios, json, xcode

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.hrjournalmyanmar.com/test.cfm"]];

__block NSDictionary *json;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                           json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:nil];
                           NSLog(@"Async JSON: %@", json);
```

I cannot convince why I got (null) return message from above even json format and coding are correct. Above coding is correct when json data (field length) is small but field length is long and large, (null) error occurred.

Comment: The first step would be to read the error that NSJSONSerialization would have returned if you had asked for it - but you pass nil for error (should be NULL because you are not passing a nil object, you are passing NULL as the address of an NSError* )

Comment: @gnasher729 how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid. Please check it in [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) or [JSON Editor](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)

Issue is with the `thumb` key, the opening `"` is missing for that key.

In your JSON it's like:

```
thumb":"http: //mmjobs.mmdroid.biz/articles/articles234."
```

It should be like:

```
"thumb":"http: //mmjobs.mmdroid.biz/articles/articles234."
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comments.

Still your JSON is not valid it contains a lot of new line characters and it makes it invalid. I solved your issue using the following method.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.hrjournalmyanmar.com/test.cfm"]];
__block NSDictionary *json;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n" withString:@""];
    jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""];
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];


   if (!error)
   {
       NSLog(@"Async JSON: %@", json);
   }
   else
   {
       NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
   }
}];
```

**Note:**

I won't recommend this approach, it's better to change the JSON at server side itself. Use the error argument, instead of passing nil to it. The error object will give you the exact error message.

Comment: even i fixed this one, still got error 2015-01-01 16:54:05.127 HR Journal[7826:128361] Async JSON: (null)

Comment: @ppshein: Can you verify your JSON using the tools I provided in my answer.

Comment: @ppshein: Also there are a lot of new line characters in between those strings. Check that.

Comment: Looks like you have one more bug to fix. Look, there is a serious attitude problem here. You are blaming your tools, Midhun demonstrated the first problem in the data, and after fixing that you still insist that NSJSONSerialization is at fault.

Comment: so.. pls try again then. I've removed new line characters but still got error. (null)

Comment: @ppshein: The error I'm getting is : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unescaped control character around character 278.) UserInfo=0x7fb7205748e0 {NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character 278.}

Comment: @ppshein: Instead of passing nil to error argument, pass a NSError object reference and check it's value

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you aren't creating a valid JSON format in your backend. If you try my snippet, works perfectly, but instead of creating my data in JSON is a NSString.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.hrjournalmyanmar.com/test.cfm"]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

                           NSString* dataReceived = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                           NSLog(@"Async JSON: %@", dataReceived);
}];
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But you are converting the data to string. So how can he access the values without parsing the JSON ? (One option is regex or NSScanner). But it won't help him.

Comment: Yap, agree with @MidhunMP how to convert nesting to josn object?